# Динамический ресайз QLabel с QPixmap с сохранением аспекта

Tags: qt

Есть контейнер `QWidget` у него заданы минимальные значения. И внутри него лейаут с `QLabel`. У `QLabel` также заданы минимальные значения. `QLabel` задаётся `QPixmap`. Когда контейнер растягивается мышью, либо наоборот стягивается нужно чтобы `QLabel` вёл себя также как при `scaledContents(true)`  только чтобы при этом аспект сохранялся. У контейнера переопределён `void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *) override` и внутри ресайз ивента выполняется масштабирование картинки `label->setPixmap(label->pixmap()->scaled(label->width(), label->height(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio))`, но это нормально отрабатывает когда контейнер увеличивается. В обратную сторону, т.е. на уменьшение контейнера это не работает корректно, потому что при увеличении контейнера картинка увеличивается до определенного размера, занимает там все пространство, и контейнер уже обратно не сжимается мышкой если тянуть за края виджета. Можно апскейлить картинку не на всё пространство виджета, а в процентном соотношении, но тогда уменьшение будет не плавным, сначала рамка упрётся в картинку, она отресайзится, затем снова. А хотелось бы чтобы отрисовка шла плавно и динамически, как при `scaledContents(true)`

Answer (score 0):

```
label->setPixmap(label->pixmap()->scaled(label->width()-0.1, label->height()-0.1, Qt::KeepAspectRatio))
```

В данном случае вы сможете уменьшать окно , но есть нюанс. Это будет происходить почучуть а не до макс минимального размера.

Чтобы это работало динамически использайте void YourWidghet::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) и в нутри него обновляйте размер.